# Count of unique words from one column of a file in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I was trying find out the count of unique words from one column of a file, and the words themselves, using a shell script. Here's what I was doing. Input file contains (filename: gnc.txt, new line after city name):

```
Male,Tyrus,Seattle
Male,Sam,Seattle
Male,Meha,Seattle
Male,John,Seattle
Male,Sam,Beijing
Male,Meha,Paris
Male,Meha,Berlin
```

As a first step I found out the number of unique names, which is 4 using below shell commands.

```
awk -F\, '{ if(!a[$2]) cnt++;a[$2]++;next}END{ print cnt }' gnc.txt
```

As a next step I want to get the list of unique names: i.e. Tyrus, Sam, Meha and John

Can someone help me in this on how to alter the above command?

Comment: In your script, the `next` is superfluous. If you simply want the names, then use `END { print cnt; for (name in a) print name }`.  If you want the name and the count of the times it appears, then use: `END { print cnt; for (name in a) print name, cnt[name] }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this awk:

```
awk -F, '{c[$2]++} END{for (i in c) print i, c[i]}' file
Tyrus 1
Sam 2
John 1
Meha 3
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. That was quick. Can you please explain this - '{c[$2]++} END. I tried to figure out, not coming properly.

Comment: `c[$2]++` first declares an array with key as `$2` if it doesn't exist and then increments its value by one.

Comment: Also if it worked out for you then consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It worked. Also, if $2 exits it increments its value by one, but not creating another space for it. Please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this:

```
cut -d',' -f2 file | sort | uniq -c
      1 John
      3 Meha
      2 Sam
      1 Tyrus
```

Answer (score 0):

this one works too

```
cat gnc.txt |  sed -e 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
 1 John
 3 Meha
 2 Sam
 1 Tyrus
```

`sed -e 's/,/ /g'`  --->  converts comma to space while printing(does not modify the file)

`awk '{print $2}'`  ---> prints only 2nd column

`sort | uniq -c`   ---> sorts words in alphabetically order and to count the words

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
Male,Tyrus,Seattle
Male,Sam,Seattle
Male,Meha,Seattle
Male,John,Seattle
Male,Sam,Beijing
Male,Meha,Paris
Male,Meha,Berlin' |
```

---

```
mawk '{ __[$2]++ } END { for (_ in __) print _, __[_] }' FS=, |
```

---

```
gsort       
        John    1
        Meha    3
        Sam     2
        Tyrus   1
```